# js not being passed from layout to views in sails

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, layout, sails.js

I added jquery and other js files into assets/js, they appear correctly on layout.js but i keep getting this msg 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined', on page source code i can see that the js scripts are added but for some reason i cant use them, the only way to make it work properly is to manually add the scripts into every view.

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/1jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/2popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/3jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<script src="/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jsgrid.js"></script>
<!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

Comment: It may be an ordering issue... are your scripts added below the `<!--SCRIPTS-->` comment where sails auto-loads in scripts during lift?

Comment: they are loaded in between the ´<!-- SCRIPTS-->´ automatically during lift, the css are working fine, its just the js

Comment: maybe you're not loading the scripts properly.. try to check the file location is correct or not..

Comment: @NilsonLagos what I mean is that maybe after the final load, a script that requires jquery is placed before your jquery script in the order (either one you add manually or a different auto-loaded script). You can manage the order exactly in your `pipeline.js` file, but I think sails default is all from dependencies in no particular order, then all others in no particular order. Can you check a loaded page to see the order?

Comment: This is a loaded page `<!--SCRIPTS-->`
`<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>`
`<script src="/js/1jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>`
`<script src="/js/2popper.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="/js/3jquery-ui.js"></script>`
`<script src="/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`
`<script src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>`
`<script src="/js/jsgrid.js"></script>`
`<!--SCRIPTS END-->`

Comment: Hmm, possibly the bootstrap datepicker should come after bootstrap, but I don't think that accounts for your error. Do you add any scripts outside this block (either links or snippets of code)? If so, before or after the block?

Comment: that was the problem, my script was loaded before the block from the layout, thanks!